# Type hints with Python ^3.10 and Pylance for VSCode

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting, pylance

I try to follow the new features for type hinting that came with Python 3.10. I use VSCode with the pylance extension.

For instance I have a methos like this in a class:

```py
def execute(
        self, query: str, return_type: str | None = None
    ) -> pd.DataFrame | list[Any] | None:
    ...
```

Then I get the following seen in the screenshot below:

[image]

So, my question is: Is Pylance not yet ready for Python 3.10 when there could be multiple return types or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I think value of `df_sync_records` might be something other than `pd.Dataframe` in runtime? In that case `NoneType` or `list` doesnt have `.loc` ?

Comment: In the case here, I can verify the the return type is `DataFrame`. I tried to `from pandas import DataFrame` and drop the `pd.` part, but the result was there same.

Comment: Can you try the old fashion way of `from typing import Union` and then declare the return type to union of those data types?

Comment: I did now, and the result is the same. Maybe Pylance never supported variable return type hints..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do this propper now.

```py
    @overload
    def execute(self, query: str, return_type: Literal["df"]) -> pd.DataFrame:
        ...

    @overload
    def execute(self, query: str, return_type: Literal["list"]) -> list[Any]:
        ...

    @overload
    def execute(self, query: str, return_type: Literal["none"]) -> None:
        ...

    def execute(self, query: str, return_type: str | None = None):
```